# How to get the visual studio 2010 icons for files in solution explorer of Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I got access to Visual studio 2012 a couple of days back and I found that the solution explorer is a bit too minimalistic for my taste.
With most icons grey and black , I have to make an extra effort to find out the file that I was looking for.

Is there a way to revert back to 2010 style icons for files ?

Comment: Join the club -> http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2819619-leave-vs-2010-theme-and-the-theme-editor-extensio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only "solution" I know if is to uninstall Visual Studio 2012.

The problem comes down to how the icons are registered.  When 2012 is installed, all the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT icon registrations are over-written with 2012.  Conceptually you could edit these registrations to "restore" or change the icon.  For example, .csproj files are linked to the first icon in the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC#\VCSPackages\csproj.dll file.  You could change that so the icon points to the first icon in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio **10.0**\VC#\VCSPackages\csproj.dll instead.  A `.reg` file to set that value could be created to set that value, for example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.csproj.11.0\DefaultIcon]
@="c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\VC#\\VCSPackages\\csproj.dll,0
```

That, when double-clicked, would "restore" the icon to the 2010 icon.  But, you'd have to do that for each and every icon you want to "restore".

#### Update:

I suppose you could write some code to search the registry and replace icons that point to 11.0 files and replace them with 10.0 files.  For example:

```
const string vsDirectory = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\";
int index = vsDirectory.IndexOf("10.0\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);

var keyNames = Registry.ClassesRoot.GetSubKeyNames();
foreach (var name in keyNames.Where(name => name.StartsWith("VisualStudio.Launcher.")))
{
    using(RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(name+@"\DefaultIcon"))
    {
        if (key == null) continue;
        var value = key.GetValue(null).ToString();
        if (!value.StartsWith(vsDirectory)) continue;
        var sb = new StringBuilder(value);
        var newValue = sb.Replace("10.0", "11.0", index, 4).ToString();
        var elements = newValue.Split(',');
        if (elements.Length <= 0) continue;
        var filename = elements[0];
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            key.SetValue(null, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

This particular bit of code only changes class root keys associated with VisualStudio.Launcher and only changes icons that are contained in a file within the "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\" directory *and* have a corresponding 10.0 file. i.e. it won't change the icon of a .cs file.  To include those files change `"VisualStudio.Launcher."` to `"VisualStudio."` It also assumes icon indexes haven't changed from 10 to 11.

I don't have 10 and 11 installed together, so I didn't test the `SetValue` of this code.  If you use the code, you need to make sure your install is in "c:\Program Files (x86)".

No warranties expressed nor implied.  Use at your own risk and only after backing up.  If it does what you want, let me know.

Answer (score -2):

```
const string vsDirectory = "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\\";
int index = vsDirectory.IndexOf("10.0\\", StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

index is -1 because "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\" doesn't actually contain the string "10.0\"

.. and therefore not one single thing happens when I run this, or rather, step through it to see if it works. Which it doesn't. Good testing effort, for something that was intended to **update the registry**